# How can I save my learning rate on each finished epoch using Callbacks?

Tags: computer-vision

I used LearningRateScheduler for my model training. I want to **save learning rates on each epoch in CSV file (or other document files)**. 
**Is there any way to save those learning  rates using callbacks?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may write a Custom Callback and save the LR in a file.

You will get it by - `self.model.optimizer.learning_rate`

 Custom Callback - [*Keras docs*](https://keras.io/guides/writing_your_own_callbacks/)

```py
class CustomCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        
        print("LR - {}".format(self.model.optimizer.learning_rate))

my_callbacks = [ CustomCallback() ]
```

> LR - <tf.Variable 'Adam/learning_rate:0' shape=() dtype=float32, **numpy=0.001**>

Comment: Thanks a lot exactly what I need!

Comment: You may mark the Answer as accepted then.

Comment: Can you please tell me from where I find mark answer option . I am a newbie in this platform.

Comment: Got it I mark your answer. Thanks a lot for helping. If you find this question should useful in this community then upvote inspire me a lot. Thank you once again,.